# Binding JSON serialized data to XAML in view

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

So basically this is an app in which I'm getting the data from a Google Spreadsheet, and its a classic (excel) table. I did the OAuth and fetching the data and now I just cant figure it out how to bind this to my MainView.xaml...

I want to bind it as a normal table (as there is like 10 columns and 40 rows). I went through the debugger, the table is fetched, the data is stored, I just don't know how to bind it to XAML. I'm trying to to this in MVVM architecture so combining, trying, looking at the HUB template but no good..Here is some code...

The MODEL - Table.cs:

```
[DataContract]
public class Table
{
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="day")]
    public int Day { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="month")]
    public int Month { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="People")]
    public string People { get; set; }
}
```

DATASOURCE:

```
//[DataContract]
//public class TablePayload
//{
//    [DataMember(Name="tables")]
//    public List<Table> Table { get; private set; }
//}
// I used the payload in a similar app, dunno if I actually need it here
public sealed class DataSource
{
    private static DataSource _dataSource = new DataSource();

    private ObservableCollection<Table> _table = new ObservableCollection<Table>();

    public ObservableCollection<Table> Table
    {
        get { return this._table; }
    }

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<Table>> GetTablesAsync()
    {
        await _dataSource.GetDataAsync();
        return _dataSource.Table;
    }

    public static async Task<Table> GetTableAsync(string id)
    {
        await _dataSource.GetDataAsync();
        var matches = _dataSource.Table.Where((table) => table.Id.Equals(id));
        if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
        return null;
    }

    private async Task GetDataAsync()
    {
        //if (this._table.Count != 0) return;

        this.Table.Clear();
        var jsonObject = await DownloadSpreadsheet.GetJson();

        for (int row = 0; row < jsonObject["rows"].Count(); row++)
        {
            Table table = new Table();
            table.Day = int.Parse(jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][0]["v"].ToString());
            table.Month = int.Parse(jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][1]["v"].ToString());
            table.Year = int.Parse(jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][2]["v"].ToString());
            table.People = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][4]["v"].ToString();

            this.Table.Add(table);
        }
    }
}
```

VIEWMODEL: MainView.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainView : Page
{

    //public ObservableCollection<SpreadSheetModel> table = new ObservableCollection<SpreadSheetModel>();
    private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

    public MainView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
    {
        get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
    }

    async private void btrRefreshData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tableData = await DataSource.GetTablesAsync();
        this.DefaultViewModel["Table"] = tableData;
    }
}
```

and the VIEW: MainView.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="Degordian_Workload_2.Views.MainView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Degordian_Workload_2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Model="using:Degordian_Workload_2.Services.Model"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<Page.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="StandardTripleLineItemTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,20,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Month}" FontFamily="Global User Interface" TextLineBounds="Tight" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding People}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Global User Interface" />


        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="120,67,1142,687">
        <Run Text="You are in Main View."/>
    </TextBlock>


    <Button x:Name="btrRefreshData"  
        Margin="1237,52,0,678"
        Content="Refresh" Click="btrRefreshData_Click"  />


</Grid>
```

[image]
Also the code is on github: https://github.com/lklancir/apps

If you could just show me an example for this or direct it, I;d be grateful! Thx in advance.

Comment: You probably need some sort of DataGrid. It's not really simple to write it for you since you haven't exactly specified what it needs to look like. If you need just a simple list of data, ListView control would probably suffice. However, if you need complex tables/grids, you might need a third-party DataGrid control, such as the one Syncfusion offers http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/sfdatagrid

Comment: Coul you just write out a simple example with my data. E.G i jsut want to write out "day" "month" "people" anywhere in the layout... just so I see where is the data source and so on, I cant get it to write out anything :( ... I don't quite understand this binding...

Comment: Assuming your DataContext is being set correctly (DataContext="{Binding Table}"), can you add a ListView somewhere in the UI to see if it works? <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StandardTripleLineItemTemplate}" />. This is very similar to how it's done in the Hub Application project template.

Comment: IT WORKSSS! Thank you! I see that I need to have this "StandardTripleLineItemTemplate", what would you suggest, how can I adapt this to my needs, are there any other templates, or I can make my own? Any advice you could give as I have "table-like" data with rows and columns